# How to add close button to bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap card using the following code:

```
 <div class="card card-outline-danger text-center">
         <span class="pull-right clickable" data-effect="fadeOut"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
          <div class="card-block">
           <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
             <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
          </blockquote>
           </div>
        </div>
```

I am using the following code to get my close button working:

```
<span class="pull-right clickable" data-effect="fadeOut"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
```

The close button is not working and I am new to bootstrap. Therefore, I need some help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This isn't a standard feature of bootstrap, so you need to bind a JS click event to the icon, and trigger it to close the parent `.card`. I also added `cursor: pointer` to the icon so that it looks like something you can click on.

```js
$('.close-icon').on('click',function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').fadeOut();
})
```

```css
.close-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-outline-danger text-center">
  <span class="pull-right clickable close-icon" data-effect="fadeOut"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
  <div class="card-block">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, some time passed since this question was raised, but still a nice way to realize a dismissible card without any custom JavaScript and only with Bootstrap CSS classes is the following: the combination of `card-header`, [the Bootstrap 4 Close Icon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/close-icon/) and [negative margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/#negative-margin) (here `.mt-n5`) on the `card-body`. The close icon gets nicely positioned within the card-header and the negative margins pull the card content closer into the header area.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="closeablecard" class="card card-hover-shadow mt-4">
    <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-bottom-0">
      <button data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#closeablecard" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body mt-n5">
      <h5 class="card-title">Your Title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem recusandae voluptate porro suscipit numquam distinctio ut. Qui vitae, ut non inventore necessitatibus quae doloribus rerum, quaerat commodi, nemo perferendis ab.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To actually close the card we can make use of the BS4 Data-API and put the the following data attributes in the button tag: `data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#closeablecard"`.
data-target is the ID of our card and data-dismiss=alert triggers the actual close event in Bootstrap.

[See a Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hennson/jbn5yfmp/)...

HTH,
hennson

Answer (score 0):

To actually close the card we can make use of the BS4 Data-API and put the the following data attributes in the button tag: data-dismiss="alert" data-target="#closeablecard". data-target is the ID of our card and data-dismiss=alert triggers the actual close event in Bootstrap.

By,
Ragul K